# Angular ng test throwing errors on the RxJS Operator

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, gojs

We are trying to run `ng test` in our Angular app and we got the below errors.

Initially, we got error on the switchMap, so to resolve that we have added pipe and then now the ng test is throwing error on the first().

But the Angular build is not throwing any errors. But those errors are coming only with `ng test` so we had to fix / find workaround on those errors every time which is not correct i think.

Do you have any idea or suggestions to overcome those errors?

Update: Every time we have to adjust the code to run the ng test. Is there any configuration in Angular so that we do not have to change Production code to make "ng test" happy?

```
ERROR in src/app/project/design/design-summary/design-summary.component.ts:94:33 - error TS2339: Property 'first' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<Design>'.
94     this.gojsService.design$.first().subscribe((design: Design) => {
                                   ~~~~~
src/app/project/design/design.component.ts:328:42 - error TS2339: Property 'first' does not exist on type 'EventEmitter<Version>'.
328     this.gojsService.changeDesign$.first().pipe(switchMap((version: Version) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best option for you is to transition to new rxjs version, from the very old one. if you remove `rxjs-compat` package from your project, compilation will also show you all the errors.
in this case moving `first()` to `.pipe(`  should fix the problem

```
this.gojsService.changeDesign$.pipe(
  first(),
  switchMap((version: Version) => {
...
```